# MS Access - me.recordset not passing to sub

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, parameter-passing, recordset

I have a form that loads a single record.  The user does what they need to do on the form...in this case, they enter a date, and a button becomes available to click to advance the record to the next step in the process.

I have a public function that is logging the activity to tblActivity, and sets the record's new Status and Location.  This Function takes 3 variables, and was working fine until today.

```
'I'm calling the function with this line from the button's Click event
  LogActivity 15, Screen.ActiveForm, Me.Recordset

Public Function LogActivity(ByVal lSID As Long, Optional fForm As Form, Optional ByRef fRS As Recordset)

  With fRS
    Do Until .EOF
      Debug.Print .Fields(5)
      .MoveNext
    Loop
  End With
...
End Function
```

This should be printing the form's Status value, but fRS is passed in with no values.  The form's recordset has values prior to being passed as the form has data.  Some how it is getting lost in the pass.  This was working fine, I have multiple buttons across 5 different forms that all call this same Function.  Suddenly today, none of them can pass the recordset.  I can think of nothing that was changed that would effect this.  Most of the changes recently involved locking down fields and the appearance of buttons at the right time...nothing related to the recordset.

Naturally, this DB is supposed to go live on Monday.

Comment: Yes, it kicks out the Runtime error 3021 - No Current Record.

The recordset in the Function has no values in anything, yet shows a recordcount of 1.

Comment: None of the ones shown, it throws that error when it gets to -
`If lSID = fRS("Status") Then
Blah`
None of the fields have any values.

Comment: Because the spirit of the error was mentioned ("fRS is passed with no values") and it isn't the line of code that is the problem...hence it has been working fine for weeks.  This issue is that the recordset is losing values on the hand off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had a backup from yesterday that was working fine.

One by one, I went through the changes I logged from yesterday and found that by changing some fields to .enabled = False and .locked = True is what was doing it.  Apparently that was enough to clear all the values when passing.

Left the fields enabled, just locked them and it passes all values correctly.

Even though this was a failure on my part, I'll leave this up in case some one else makes the same mistake I made.

**** Update ****
I also found out that if I did a 
`fRS.movelast
fRS.movefirst`
before anything else, it found the data.  Not sure why it started happening, but these two things seem to have fixed it completely.